# Collision detection with particles in Cocos2d

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, collision-detection, particles

I am using CCParticleSystemQuad to create a particle effect. Now I would like to test for collisions with a CGRect from my Cocos2d scene. I listed another subject similar to this one and got a little closer however I still do not have the full solution so I have re-listed with a slightly different subject title.

I have half of the solution. I can get the position of each particle and can test for collisions, now I would like to set the positions of each when they collide.
I am currently subclassing the CCParticleSystemQuad and then adding my own getter like so:

```
-(tCCParticle*)getQuadParticle:(int)quadIndex
{
    return &particles[quadIndex];
}
```

Then in my Cocos2d scene I can get the particle and the position:

```
tCCParticle *particle = [emitter getQuadParticle:i];
CGPoint pos = particle->pos;
```

This works but warns that CCParticleSystemQuad may not respond to getQuadParticle. Which is a concern, but what I would like to do now is set the position from the scene in a similar fashion such as:

```
[emitter setParticlePos:i newPosition:newPos];
```

However I am not sure how to make a setter that does this that works from my scene. I don't want to do collision detion inside the particle subclass if possible.

I started another topic of similar nature called "How to get particle position in Cocos2d (iphone)" and I was told to overide the "update" method or the "updateQuadWithParticle" method but I am unsure how to go about this exactly.

If someone could show me an example of how to do this I would be most grateful.

Comment: You want collision detection on each individual particle?  I can tell you how to detect collisions on an emitter but I don't think that's what you want.

Comment: Yes, I need to manage each particle individually. Any ideas?

Comment: Not really.  Just guessing as I haven't looked into the particle systems much yet, but you don't really have to use the built in particle systems (or you could override them).  Each particle is just the sprite displayed with a different tint and opacity (I'm guessing).  Your best bet is probably to delve into the Cocos2d Code and override some methods adding in the ability for each sprite/particle to have it's own body attached.

Comment: If you manage it please post how you did it :)

Comment: Okay. I'll have a look into it but it's probably beyond my skill sets. I made a particle system before but it performed pretty slowly, however I wasn't using Cocos2d at the time so I might have better luck this time. Thanks for your help. I'll be sure to post results if I have any success. Cheers!

Comment: One idea is to create your own particle system using box2d. Then you will have collision as well. But it will probably be pretty tough on the device.

Comment: I think your best bet may be to try posting this question on the Cocos2D forums if you're still looking for answer.  I did a quick search for particle system collision detection in Cocos 2D (http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/search.php?q=collision+with+particles).  Looks like there's been some active discussion on the topic.  Sorry I can't answer the question myself.

Answer (score 0):

> This works but warns that CCParticleSystemQuad may not respond to
>   getQuadParticle.

For the warning, make sure your emitter is made from your subclass (and not a regular CCParticleSystemQuad), and that your getter method is declared in the interface (.h file) and defined in the implementation (.m file).

Looking at the [API](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/latest-stable/_c_c_particle_system_8h_source.html), I don't see a method for `setParticlePos:newPosition:` but there is something that looks similar: `-(void) updateQuadWithParticle:(tCCParticle*)particle newPosition:(CGPoint)pos;`

I have not used it, but a glance at the source suggests it does what you need.

So maybe try 
`[emitter updateQuadWithParticle:particle newPosition:newPos];`

Hope that's helpful.